# How can I collapse a fat toolbar into a one-liner?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have a toolbar that I need to collapse, but all the examples I've seen of a CollapsingToolbarLayout just collapse an image into a minimal toolbar. Is it possible to collapse the following into a one-line toolbar that includes only a title?

[image]

Here is the XML for the above toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:title="@string/app_header"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:titleTextAppearance="@style/ToolbarTitle">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/login"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/login" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/login_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorEnabled"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/login"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/intro"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/account_switch" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/intro_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorEnabled"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/intro_page"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/video"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/video" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/video_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorEnabled"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/video_page"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/tutorial"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/book" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/tutorial_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorEnabled"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/tutorial_page"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/edit_profile"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/account_edit" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/edit_profile_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorDisabled"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/create_profile2"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/in_common"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/account_search" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/in_common_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorDisabled"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/what_in_common2"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/edit_colors"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/palette" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/edit_colors_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorDisabled"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/settings_color"
                        />
                    </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/software_license"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/file_outline" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/software_license_text"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textColor="@color/colorEnabled"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:text="@string/eula"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: What is the output you need..? you need the only title after the collapse or you need all the item in a single line after collapse..?

Comment: add a TabLayout instead

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the toolbar to collapse, only to remove the code almost immediately. It turns out that the CollapsingToolbarLayout is incompatible with views that contain scrollable objects, like ListViews, as mine does.